# Automated way of displaying the date structure of a time series in basic R plot()

Tags: r, plot, time-series

```
install.packages('RCurl')
require(RCurl)
install.packages('zoo')
require(zoo)

x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/DATASETS/gh-pages/interest%20in%20soccer%20in%20the%20US.csv")
soccer <- read.csv(textConnection(x), header=T)
s <- zoo(soccer)
plot.ts(s$soccer_US)
```

results in

[image]

but I need the x-axis to be the dates.

I know there are a good number of posts on the same topic, although many of them - including some I might have posted - entail `xaxt="n"`, which seems to be a very circuitous way to go about it.

Is there a simpler way of preserving the date structure of the x axis in basic `plot()`?

Comment: You don't need to put install.packages statements into R questions.  require should be used within if statements. Use library outside if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code in the question the zoo(...) command is used incorrectly.   See ?zoo to get information on it.

To do this read the file into a zoo object, z, using yearmon class for the times and then just use plot or autoplot.

```
library(zoo)

u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/DATASETS/gh-pages/interest%20in%20soccer%20in%20the%20US.csv"
z <- read.csv.zoo(u, FUN = as.yearmon)
plot(z)
```

or replace last line with:

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearmon()
```

### Note

The first few lines of the file look like this:

```
L <- readLines(u)
writeLines(head(L))
```

giving:

```
date,count 
2004-01,25 
2004-02,29 
2004-03,33 
2004-04,36 
2004-05,37
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Using the first part of your answer, how can I make the axis less crowded and the labels vertical `las=2`? Also, I was working on an alternative method that almost worked, and it wouldn't be fair to now modify the OP to pre-empt your answer, but I will post as a separate question very shortly, and send you the link.

Comment: Here is the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68198956/15183594).

Comment: It depends what you want but this will just show the years: `plot(z, xaxt = "n"); axis(1, unique(as.integer(time(z))))`   Note that yearmon class measures time in years so taking the integer part gives the year.  You can add las=2 to the axis command if you wish but it fit for me even without that.

Comment: I am trying to do it by year and month, and if possible avoiding the `zoo` package as in the secondary question linked above, and dutifully closed by now.

Comment: plot(z) already draws ticks for year and month and draws labels for the years using your data so it seems already ok but if you want longer ticks for the years keeping the shorter ticks for the months except January then  `plot(z); axis(1, unique(as.integer(time(z))), tcl = -1)`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did use `zoo` as in the OP. However, my preferred method was to avoid the need for packages as much as possible (as in the comments). The following works the way I intended it:

```
require(RCurl)

x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/DATASETS/gh-pages/interest%20in%20soccer%20in%20the%20US.csv")
dat <- read.csv(textConnection(x))
dat$date <- as.Date(paste(dat$date,"-01",sep=""), format="%Y-%m-%d")

plot(dat, type='l', xaxt='n', lwd=3, col='firebrick', xlab='', ylab='')
at1 <- seq(min(dat$date), max(dat$date)+10, by="3 months")
axis.Date(1, at=at1, format="%b %d", las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
```

This is a screen capture of this code run on Google Colab:

[image]

Comment: This gives errors when I try to run, it on my Windows PC using "R version 4.1.0 RC (2021-05-16 r80303)", it does use packages even though it claims not to, it uses at least one bad practice which I previously mentioned and it is twice as long as the accepted answer even though the question asked for a simple answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I just re-run it verbatim from the script on this post (including `install.packages('RCurl')` because I used Google Colab (brand new runtime session), and it worked without a glitch. The only package used was naturally `RCurl` to allow me to get the dataset from GitHub.

Comment: This may depend on the platform.  It seems it is related to the RCurl package. I left a comment rather than downvoting in case it does run on some people's machines.